# Pivot for Object Columns (without aggregation)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like

```
ObjColA   ObjColB
2021-10-13   ABC
2021-10-13   DEF
2021-10-13   XYZ
2021-10-14   ABC
2021-10-14   PQR
2021-10-14   DEF
2021-10-14   XYZ
```

And I like to turn into a pivot-like diff such that values of ObjColA turn as headers and the rows for them become the ObjColB values corresponding to it.

```
2021-10-13   2021-10-14
    ABC      ABC
    DEF      PQR
    XYZ      DEF
             XYZ
```

I understand pivot and pivot table need aggregation method; can you advise how i can achieve this

Comment: Check Q/A no. 10 in dupe.

Comment: Q/Q no. 10 ? Sorry what is this ?

Comment: Sorry, it is Q/A  Question and Answer